# crypt in c++ returning different strings(or no string at all)

Tags: c++, linux, crypt

I am trying to create a shadowfile-like txt file and I am using crypt to produce the hash. I ask for password via terminal and i produce a pseudo-random salt. I give these two values in crypt function but it creates a different hash everytime or nothing at all and I cannot get what's wrong with my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<ctime>
#include<crypt.h>
#include<unistd.h>


using namespace std;

/*====== READ STRING DYNAMICALLY ======*/

char* readFromTerminal() {

    int length = 0; //counts number of characters
    char c; //holds last read character
    char *input;

    input = (char *) malloc(sizeof (char)); //Allocate initial memory

    if (input == NULL) //Fail if allocating of memory not possible
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory!");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') //until end of line
    {
        realloc(input, (sizeof (char))); //allocate more memory
        input[length++] = c; //save entered character
    }

    input[length] = '\0'; //add terminator
    return input;
}

/*====== GENERATE PSEUDO RANDOM SALT VALUE ======*/

char* generateSalt() {

    const char alphanum[] =
            "0123456789"
            "!@#$%^&*"
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //salt alphanum

    int alphanumLength = sizeof (alphanum) - 1; // alphanum lenght

    char *salt; //salt string

    salt = (char *) malloc(sizeof (char)); //Allocate initial memory

    if (salt == NULL) //Fail if allocating of memory not possible
    {
        printf("Could not allocate memory!");
        exit(1);
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        realloc(salt, (sizeof (char))); //allocate more memory

        salt[i] = alphanum[rand() % alphanumLength]; //generate a random character from the alphanum
    }

    salt[21] = '\0'; //add terminator

    return salt;
}

/*====== MAIN ======*/
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char *username, *password, *salt, *hash;

    ofstream myshadow("myshadow.txt", ios::out);

    cout << "Enter your username: ";
    username = readFromTerminal();
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    password = readFromTerminal();

    salt = generateSalt();
    hash = (char *) malloc(30 * sizeof (char)); //Allocate memory for hash
    hash = crypt(password, salt);

    myshadow << username << ":" << hash;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why is this tag C

Comment: now it is not if it is so much of a problem for you

Comment: Each time you use current time as a seed (srand(time(NULL));), so it is obvious that each time you have different hash (i.e. you use different salt each time).

Comment: Thats just normal. If you change the salt the hash will change as well.

Comment: and what about when it is not producing nothing at all ?

Comment: Generally realloc is used incorrectly as I can see...

Comment: yes i get warnings but what is wrong

Comment: Read http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc and compare with your usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot to improve here!

- you use raw `char *` when C++ comes with `std::string`
- you use explicit `malloc` and `realloc` that alone let think that problems will soon arrive

Manual memory management requires very cautious programming. Here the error is caused by an incorrect use of `realloc`: the size parameter gives the new **total** allocated size, not an increment. So you should keep track of the allocated size, increase it and call realloc with that new value. And as `realloc` may return a new block of memory, you should always use:

```
input = (char *) realloc(input, new_size);
```

BTW, equivalent problem in `generateSalt`...

But all is already included in C++, thanks to `std::getline`! And in addition, the `<random>` module comes with great generators when old `rand` suffers number of defaults (just google for *rand vs. random*)

So the code could be stripped down to:

```
include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <random>


using namespace std;

std::string generateSalt() {

    const char alphanum[] =
            "0123456789"
            "!@#$%^&*"
            "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //salt alphanum

    std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, sizeof(alphanum)-1); //Uniform distribution on an interval
    char salt[22];          // 21 useful characters in salt (as in original code)
    for(char& c: salt) {
        c = alphanum[dis(gen)];
    }
    salt[21] = 0;
    return std::string(salt);
}

/*====== MAIN ======*/
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    string username, password, salt, hash;

    ofstream myshadow("myshadow.txt", ios::out);

    cout << "Enter your username: ";
    if (! getline(cin, username)) return 1;
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    if (! getline(cin, password)) return 1;

    salt = generateSalt();
    hash = crypt(password.c_str(), salt.c_str());

    myshadow << username << ":" << hash;
    return 0;
}
```

Another nice side effect of using C++ strings is that allocation **and deallocation** is automatically handled, no need to call `free`...